# Can FFMPEG extract images from a video with timestamps?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract frames from a video  and get the exact timestamps of each frame extracted (on a picture).

To extract frames from video without timestamps I use this syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i video.wmv -r 0.08 -f image2 -s 512x384 video2%%4d.jpg
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the [`drawtext`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter. Your build will need to be compiled with `--enable-libfreetype`. Most static builds of `ffmpeg` for Windows and Linux appear to support this filter. See the [FFmpeg download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links.

## timestamp

### duration

[image: duration]

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf: text='%{pts\:hms}': x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" image%03d.png
```

### current time

[image: current time]

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf: text='%{localtime}': x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" image%03d.png
```

## timecode

[image: timecode]

PAL 25 fps non drop frame:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" image%03d.png
```

This is adapted from the [Burnt in Timecode](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide#BurntinTimecode) example in the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/). The `r` option will set the timecode frame rate.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
with some adaptations for Windows works well. but I extract all frames of movie with timstamp, I need to extract one frame every 10 seconds. I added something and now it is ok.
At this moment appears on picture me hh:mm:ss:frame. Is possible to not appear after :ss the number of frame?

Comment: This is the syntax I use now:

ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 0.08 -f image2 -s 512x384 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/WINDOWS/Fonts/arial.ttf: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1 " video%%4d.png

Comment: @BillMarc : could you please post the adaptation that you did to make it working in windows