# Is it possible to modify the timecode format of ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I am trying to overlay my video with the timecode.

Currently, I have this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -vf "drawtext=:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/myfont.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=$framerate: fontcolor=white: x=700: y=555" -crf $quality -vcodec libx264 output.avi
```

This works but uses the default format of hh:mm:ss:ff.

Is it possible to just display the elapsed time in seconds only?

If not, is there another way of displayed the number of elapsed seconds?

Comment: $framerate and $quality are bash variables.

Comment: First of all, good morning. I did not catch your name. Stackoverflow might be a better forum for these type of questions.

Comment: @Firee nah, since this is about using a tool rather than programming, SuperUser is the best place for it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yeah..I debated between the two and chose superuser. Is it bad practice to post on both?

Comment: Yes. Crossposting is not recommended, and several users probably check both sites anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can FFMPEG extract images from a video with timestamps?](http://superuser.com/questions/575854/can-ffmpeg-extract-images-from-a-video-with-timestamps). Example in answer shows how to add duration timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

is possible with strftime and basetime you can put initial date and time and in text paramter you can set the format of the date and time. ex:

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mp4 -vf "drawtext=expansion=strftime: basetime=$(date +%s -d'2019-11-22 14:06:01')000000: text='%d/%m/%Y %H\\:%M\\:%S': r=12: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: fontsize=42" outvideo.mp4
```